# Manual breakpoints not working on remote VM in XDebug for PHP

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug, remote-debugging

I've been setting up XDebug for PHP on a remote VM, with PHPStorm as the IDE/client. I see a lot of questions about this on the site, but none about this situation...

I'm coding on a Windows machine, with PHPStorm synchronizing files automatically with my dev environment on a Linux VM. I have a tunnel on port 9001 from that VM back to my local machine. I'm trying to debug command line PHP scripts, and I've got this far:

- The xdebug_break() function works.
- If 'Break at first line in PHP scripts' is checked, I can step through scripts from the beginning, but...
- Manual breakpoints don't work!

Communication between my IDE and the XDebug instance seems to be fine, as I'm able to step through as long as it's from an xdebug_break() or the start of a script (though the IDE doesn't highlight the current line).

Looking at the xdebug.remote_log, I see the breakpoint being set on my local, Windows file instead of the path on the server - this seems like a problem...

```
<- breakpoint_set -i 7 -t line -f file://D:/git/php/php/tests/lookatme.php -n 8
```

(The double php/php is correct.)

If I trick it by symlinking a "/D:/git/php/php/" directory on my VM to the actual PHP directory and then run a PHP script, it actually works – but only if PHP is run from the root directory.

As far as I know, my mapping in Settings/PHP/Servers is correct - am I right in thinking that only the root folder of my PHP repository needs to be mapped to its equivalent on the remote server?

```
D:\git\php\php -> /company/mnt/codebase/DEVWEB/php/
```

My xdebug.ini:

```
xdebug.default_enable=0
xdebug.overload_var_dump=0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir=/tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name="cachegrind.out.%s.%t"
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_mode="req"
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.log
```

Scripts are run with the environment variable:

```
export XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=PHPSTORM"
```

Path mappings in PHPStorm:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItOYB.png

Thanks for any thoughts!

Comment: Most likely path mappings is incorrect Please show screenshot of `Settings | PHP | Servers`.

Comment: Edited the description to add the screenshot!

Comment: Is port 9001 opened?

Comment: It is - communication on port 9001 is going fine, through a tunnel between the local machine and VM (through Putty: R9001 -> localhost:9001)

Comment: Just to be 100% clear: Please note that **xdebug works with final/resolved file names ONLY**, therefore `/company/mnt/codebase/DEVWEBPHP354/php/` should be actual real path and not contain any symlinks in it.

Comment: The best way to see what is wrong here would be to look into actual log files (from both xdebug side as well as PhpStorm: http://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-1202 ). Right now for me it looks like path mapping issue.

Comment: BTW -- what sort of lines are those (where breakpoint is set)? It should be simple 1 liner -- xdebug may not always break on multiline statement (e.g. array declaration etc).

Comment: Good thought, LazyOne - I double-checked and I don't see any symlinks in the path I'm using.

Comment: One thought: what should my 'host' and 'port' be in the server configuration above the path mappings? Could they be the issue, or does the way I'm getting communication back at all indicate that these settings are OK?

Comment: `Host` is basically a domain name used to access that website. `Port` -- port number used for the same purpose (80 by default). If this entry was created by PhpStorm itself (as result of using [zero-config approach](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm), for example), then you should leave those values unchanged.

Comment: Still -- consider providing raw logs.

Comment: BTW -- are you debugging via browser (website) or some custom CLI script. What PhpStorm version do you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for everyone's help and pointers - in the end it turned out I was missing an environment variable on my remote machine:

export PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=RemotePHP"

where RemotePHP is the name of the server set up in Settings > PHP > Servers and selected in the debug configuration. Presumably, without this it didn't know how to map the incoming breakpoint to the right file.

Comment: You da real mvp. This worked for me. You can also add a file to /etc/profile.d named anything.sh and put PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=RemotePHP" in it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to map every single file. It works for me with a remote server.

Comment: No need to map "every single file" **for PhpStorm**. Mapping for folder will be extended to all subfolders and files in it.

Comment: He has only root mapped. Xdebug configuration is sometimes not logical.